# Javascript - Json getting the value from the table using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am new in ajax and json. and in my select option i have list of products there. and if i press any of the product it will show its price and the supplier. but what happened to my code is it shows both product and supplier but not in there specific fields. Here is the [**Example**](http://prntscr.com/ccg5ar)
The 550.00 is the price and asdadsadsadsadsadsad there is the name of the supplier. so the output must be in their specific fields.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $("#prod-names").change(function(){
    var prodid = $("#prod-names option:selected").attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:800/client_ayos/administrator/createpromoajax/"+prodid,
        type: "POST",


        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var json = JSON.parse(data);

            $("#orig-price").val(json); //val =  value of #orig-price
            $("#supplier").val(json); //val =  value of #orig-price

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('Error !');
                }
    })
});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function createpromoajax($id){
    //echo json_encode($this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['productid'] = $this->AdminModel->get_prodid($id);

    $price = $data['productid']->price;
    $supplier = $data['productid']->supplier;

    $ajaxproduct = array(
        $data['productid']->price,
        $data['productid']->supplier,
        );


    echo json_encode($ajaxproduct);

}
```

PS: I've also encountering this kind of error but still it shows the correct output but not in the specific fields

VM13100:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is a lot to simplify your controller and js structure
try something like that

here is the php part

```
public function createpromoajax($id)
{
    $objProduct = $this->AdminModel->get_prodid($id);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($objProduct);
}
```

and your javascript part

```
$("#prod-names").change(function(){

    var prodid = $("#prod-names option:selected").attr("value");
    var url = "http://localhost:800/client_ayos/administrator/createpromoajax/"+prodid;

    $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
        $("#orig-price").val(data.price);
        $("#supplier").val(data.supplier); //val =  value of #orig-price
    });
});
```

i'm not sure what it means "unexptected token..." but i think you already output some html before the createpromoajax function - in order to verify this you could try to call your function directly and see what your browser gets as output.

Comment: thanks it also helped. but my i ask what is the use of  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` the content header is just an information about the type of the returned data - i'm not sure but i think jQuery doesnt care whether you use it or not - but you could try it.

if you still face your problem with the unexpected token thing - call the url directly and show us your output

Comment: i tried your code and still it has the same output like the other comments code. which is correct, but it still show the unexpected token thing here. http://prntscr.com/cch3wi

Comment: i've already found the error. i forgot that i also tried putting my ajax code to my custom.js  which the code there is still has an error. and still btw thanks for answering my question and making the codes simplier

Answer (score 0):

change this in php

```
    $ajaxproduct = array(
        "price"=>$data['productid']->price,
        "supplier"=>$data['productid']->supplier,
    );
```

then you can write

```
    $("#orig-price").val(json.price); //val =  value of #orig-price
    $("#supplier").val(json.supplier);
```

Comment: it says in console Uncaught TypeError: json.split is not a function

Comment: i'm sorry. it works already.thanks but when the output is already there in the console part it keeps on showing this kind of error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. what does it mean?

Comment: change this line 
var json = JSON.parse(data); to 
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: i changed it the way you said but it happened it didnt show the output in the field and the error still there

Comment: have you printed anything other than array ? or what console.log(data); displaying ?

Comment: No i just followed your code. the console.log(data) when i chose a product then in console it shows there the whole code of my page and after that the error VM13906:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: try to write exit; after json_encode() please like this :
echo json_encode($ajaxproduct);
exit;